# debug assert vector iterator not dereferncable with find_if

Tags: c++

I want to convert my for loop into a find_if lambda but I Always get the same result vector iterator not dereferncable.

```
void SearchObjectDescription(std::vector<std::string>& input, Player & player)
{
    //--local variable
    bool found = false;

    //std::find_if
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(),[&](Player player)
    {
        if ((player.InInventory((*i)) ) == true)
        {
            std::cout << (player.GetInventory().ItemByName((*i))).ExamineObject() << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Object not in invetory!" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    });
    //original for loop
    //for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = input.begin()+1; i != input.end(); i++)
    //{
    //  if (player.InInventory((*i))== true)
    //  {
    //      std::cout << (player.GetInventory().ItemByName((*i))).ExamineObject() << std::endl;
    //      found = true;
    //      break;
    //  }
    //}
    //if (found ==false)
    //{
    //  std::cout << "Object not in invetory!" << std::endl;
    //}
}
```

Can some one help me please?

Comment: You may not use the iterator i in the lambda if ((player.InInventory((*i)) ) == true) because it is not initialized yet and in any case such a statement does not make sense.

Comment: As others suggested. `i` is your result of `find_if` with lambda, hence, it doesn't make sense to use it inside the lambda body.

Comment: I got lost in all the redundant parentheses in that `if` statement. Also, comparing a Boolean variable to `true` is pointless; just test it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about the lambda wrongly. The `std::find_if` function takes, as it's third argument, a lambda that takes an element of the vector, and return if it's the element you searched for.

The purpose of the lambda is to take an element and tell if it's the right one.

Yet, your lambda don't receive an element of your vector of string, but takes a player as parameter. But you obviously don't have a list of player, you have a list of string. Why should the element to check should be a `Player`?

Instead, capture your player variable and receive the element to check. It would look like this:

```
void SearchObjectDescription(std::vector<std::string>& input, Player & player)
{
    auto i = std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(),[&](const std::string& item)
    {
        // item is equal to the current element being checked
        // player is captured by reference because of [&]

        // if the item `item` is in inventory, return true.
        return player.InInventory(item);
    });

    if (i != input.end()) {
        // if it's not equal to the end, *i is the found item.
    }
}
```

Note that in C++14, you can receive `auto&&` in your lambda, and it will be deduced to `string&`:

```
std::find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [&](auto&& item)
{ 
     // type of item is std::string&

     // ...
});
```

Comment: @StievenVermoesen this is not related to this answer. You should either ask another question or edit this one, but I won't read that comment.

Comment: what if the forloop has more than one if statement how do you do you turn that into a lambda?

Comment: Well... You can put these statements inside the lambda, as long as you return a `bool`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `i` iterator inside of your lambda, because it is not initialized until after `std::find_if()` exits.  You need to use the input parameter of the lambda instead, which will be a `std::string` from the `vector`, not a `Player` object.

Also, you are not checking the return value of `std::find_if()` to make sure you have a valid iterator before dereferencing it.

You did not translate your `for` loop to a lambda-based `std::find_if()` correctly.  Try this instead:

```
void SearchObjectDescription(std::vector<std::string>& input, Player & player)
{
    auto i = std::find_if(input.begin()+1, input.end(),
        [&](const std::string &s) { return player.InInventory(s); });

    if (i != input.end())
    {
        std::cout << (player.GetInventory().ItemByName(*i)).ExamineObject() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Object not in inventory!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```